# How to change content of a posted link's description

Tags: facebook-like, meta-tags

I've recently added some Facebook content to my webpage, enabling the "like" and "send" buttons, found here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/, to my webpage.

I find when I 'like' my webpage, and the status appears on my Facebook wall, the description shown under the link-title does not match what my meta-tags are described as. Where is this description coming from? Is there a way to change it?

I've added and changed several styles of meta tags (meta title, meta name, meta description, etc). Nothing seems to change this description. I've also cleaned my Safari caché after testing new content, with no more luck.

I know I'm looking right at the problem.

If you look at the link's source code, you can see there is no indication of this description.

Please ask me for the website address if necessary.

Please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This answer comes a little late but Facebook caches all pages internally. The easiest way for facebook to read your tags is to scrape the website by going to http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and entering the URL of your website. This will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit unclear about what exactly your problem is, but on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ Step 2 - Get Open Graph Tags, it will generate the appropriate meta tags with the correct syntax.  If the problem isn't fixed with that method, I would suggest looking into the PHP Facebook API because I had a lot of problems that I was frankly too lazy to figure out with the JavaScript Facebook stuff that I could easily correct and design with the PHP version.  Hopefully this at least points you in the right direction.  Maybe some code too, ya?

> EDIT: By the way, the generated meta tags look something along these lines:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:type" content="" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="" />
etc.
```

EDIT 2: It just occurred to me as well that, if you have a Facebook Page, the information will be pulled from there.  However, if you don't and are trying to use a link to a website, you can/should make a Facebook App for Webpages that will allow you to customize the description, title, etc. and all that other jazz you're probably having troubles with.

Comment: it is not recommended to use the old API... **especially** not out of laziness... Spend some time reading about the [new api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is place the correct og:tags into your page...[This link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) will tell you what tags to place on your page according to the content you have.  There is also the facebook [url linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) that you can use to test your og:tags...
Hope this helps!
Good luck!